# How to Loop in BigQuery for four consecutive weeks for last six months data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table in big query for example like following.(Partitioned on date). I have to write standard sql query for this problem mentioned below in details.

```
student_id     date      duration(in hours)
  1          2020-05-10   7             
  2          2020-05-10   8
  3          2020-05-10   8
  1          2020-05-11   8
  2          2020-05-11   7
  3          2020-05-12   6
```

This is table where we are appending data almost every day so data will be growing very fast.
I have to find student_ids who have attendance of more than 7 hours for 4 consecutive weeks(checking each day and this week will be increment by 1 week for last months.) in last six months and convert  student type as good student. For example in programming language.

```
for(start week->1 - end_week-> 4 till last six months):
      if duration >=7 for date
        boolean true
      start_week = 2 //start week is incremented by 1 week for next loop
      end_week = 5
```

For any student if any 4 consecutive weeks from last six months data duration is more than equal to 7 hours then he is good student. This look like very challenging to me as I am average in bigquery and mysql. I do not know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> find student_ids who have attendance of **more than 7 hours for 4 consecutive weeks**(checking each day and this week will be increment by 1 week for last months.) **in last six months** and convert student **type as good student**

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(duration_4_weeks, qualify_for_6_month_condition),
  IF(qualify_for_6_month_condition AND
    MAX(duration_4_weeks) OVER(PARTITION BY student_id) >= 7, 
    'good student', 
    NULL
  ) type
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    SUM(duration) OVER(
      PARTITION BY student_id 
      ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date) 
      RANGE BETWEEN 27 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) duration_4_weeks, 
    date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) qualify_for_6_month_condition
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

Comment: Thanks modified a little bit as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example of your use case

```
# Only for initiate the test with your data
with sample as (
  select 1 as ID,  DATE("2020-05-10") as d, 7 as hour
  union all             
  select 2 as ID,  DATE("2020-05-10") as d, 8 as hour
  union all
  select 3 as ID,  DATE("2020-05-10") as d, 8 as hour
  union all
  select 1 as ID,  DATE("2020-05-11") as d, 8 as hour
  union all
  select 2 as ID,  DATE("2020-05-11") as d, 7 as hour
  union all
  select 3 as ID,  DATE("2020-05-12") as d, 6 as hour
), 
# Create an array of date to take into account the missing days (important for the sum over the 28 previous days)
date_array as (
  select  dd from UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-05-10', '2020-05-15', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) dd
), 
# Product of existing IDs and possible date on the range
data_grid as (
  select distinct ID, dd from sample, date_array
), 
# Perform a right outer join to add missing date to the logs that you have in your sample data
merged_data as (
select data_grid.ID,d,hour,dd from sample RIGHT outer join data_grid on sample.d = data_grid.dd and sample.ID = data_grid.ID
)
# Sum per ID the 27 previous day in sliding windows (every day, the day and the last 27 are added)
select ID,dd, SUM(hour)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY ID
    ORDER BY dd
    ROWS BETWEEN 27 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS total_purchases
  from merged_data
```

Comment: Thanks for response , one issue is ID can be many not limited.

Comment: I mean it can be 100 or more than that in that case we have to do many union all

Comment: No, the union all at the beginning was only to simulate your source data. Perform a query in your real database to get these data!

Comment: Thanks I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, truncate the date to the week and aggregate.  Then use window functions to get the flag you want and filter:

```
select t.*
from (select student_id, date_trunc(date, week) as wk, sum(duration) as dur,
             min(sum(dur)) over (partition by student_id
                                 order by unix_date(min(date_trunc(date, week)))
                                 range between 21 preceding and current row
                                ) as min_4week_dur
             min(min(date_trunc(date, week))) over (partition by student_id) as min_wk
      from t
      group by 1, 2
     ) t
where datediff(min_wk, wk, week) >= 3 and
      min_4week_dur > 7;
```

The two key ideas are:

- The minimum duration is calculating the minimum weekly duration over the running four week period.
- Valid students only qualify on or after their fourth week.

Comment: It is not showing any result in big query console. Why we are using between 21 preceding and current row not 28 for four weeks. Please if it is possible, can you please explain this query.

Comment: This uses 21 because 4 weeks is three preceding weeks plus the current week.  Run the query without the outer `where` clause to see what the subquery is returning.

Comment: Thanks if i am commenting

Comment: Thanks commenting  -- datediff(min_wk, wk, week) >= 3  and duration i am taking more than 300(actual duration from my table for each day) then result there is some issue with consecutive week first there is no any date of   2020-05-03 actual date for this id started with 2020-05-05 .                         student_id,wk,dur,min_4week_dur,min_wk  
1,2020-05-03,1710,1710,2020-05-03
1,2020-05-10,1400,1400,2020-05-03
1,2020-05-17,2425,1400,2020-05-03
1,2020-05-24,2236,1400,2020-05-03
1,2020-05-31,2309,1400,2020-05-03
1,2020-06-07,1286,1286,2020-05-03
1,2020-09-06,48183,48183,2020-05-03

Comment: @akashkumar . . . If you want consecutive weeks, use the logic in the query now.  If you want the most recent 4 weeks in the data, use the `row_number()` instead.